Print long receipts using PrinterJob in Java
Here I'm using PrinterJob to print my receipts from Java.
The code is working fine, but my problem is, when the number of item is increased the receipts is not printing completely.
Here is my code:
public void printCard(String code) throws PrinterException, ParseException {
        Printable contentToPrint = new Printable() {
            @Override
            public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
                int y=30;
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
                g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());
                if (pageIndex > 0) {
                    return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
                } //Only one page
                y += 15;
                g2d.drawString("INVOICE CUM BILL OF SUPPLY", 30, y);
                y += 15;
                g2d.drawString("-----------------------------------------------------", 20, y);
                y += 20;
                g2d.drawString("Invoice No :12345", 20, y);
                y += 15;
                g2d.drawString("Date & Time : 01/01/2024", 20, y);
                y += 15;
                g2d.drawString("Customer : XXXX", 20, y);
                y += 15;
                g2d.drawString("Mobile :00000000", 20, y);
                y += 15;
                g2d.drawString("-----------------------------------------------------", 20, y);
                y += 15;
                g2d.drawString("#", 20, y);
                g2d.drawString("Description", 40, y);
                y += 13;
                g2d.drawString("HSN", 20, y);
                g2d.drawString("Qty", 70, y);
                g2d.drawString("Rate", 120, y);
                g2d.drawString("Gst%", 165, y);
                y += 13;
                g2d.drawString("Gst", 90, y);
                g2d.drawString("Amount", 150, y);
                y += 11;
                g2d.drawString("-----------------------------------------------------", 20, y);
                    y += 18;
                    g2d.drawString("1", 18, y);
                    g2d.drawString("Item 1", 40, y);
                    y += 15;
                    g2d.drawString("802332", 20, y);
                    g2d.drawString("1", 70, y);
                    g2d.drawString("123", 120, y);
                    g2d.drawString("0", 165, y);
                    y += 15;
                    g2d.drawString("0", 90, y);
                    g2d.drawString("123", 150, y);
                y += 20;
                g2d.drawString("-----------------------------------------------------", 20, y);
                y += 15;
                g2d.drawString("Sub Total : 123.00", 20, y);
                y += 15;
                g2d.drawString("Discount : 0.0 ", 20, y);
                y += 15;
                g2d.drawString("Total GST : 0.0", 20, y);
                y += 20;
                g2d.drawString("Net Bill Amount: 123.00 ", 20, y);
                y += 11;
                g2d.drawString("-----------------------------------------------------", 20, y);
                y += 15;
                g2d.drawString("Auth Sign", 57, y);
                y += 30;
                g2d.drawString("for co", 65, y);
                y += 13;
                g2d.drawString("Thank you for shopping with us", 10, y);
                y += 15;
                g2d.drawString("For Online Shopping ", 57, y);
                y += 13;
                g2d.drawString("Visit our website ", 60, y);
                y += 13;
                g2d.drawString("www.abc.com ", 58, y);
                return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
            }
        };
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
        if (service != null) {
            try {
                job.setPrintService(service);
            } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
        try {
            PageFormat pageFormat = new PageFormat();
            pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
            Paper pPaper = pageFormat.getPaper();
            pPaper.setImageableArea(0, 0, pPaper.getWidth(), pPaper.getHeight() );
            pageFormat.setPaper(pPaper);
            System.out.println("PAGE height  == "+pPaper.getHeight());
            job.setPrintable(contentToPrint, pageFormat);
            job.print();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }

In the above code I use Paper and this method create a default paper size.
I can't specify the paper Height because each and every receipts are different height.
So please refer my code and give a solution for this.
